# print no match found only once after iterating all entires from input file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I know there is a way to do it but I can't seem to remember now.
I have a small shell script which has a simple while loop and it iterates through a CSV file and has an if else loop inside it. The problem is for every line the while loop iterates the if else statement prints a no match found until it finds a match or it keeps printing no match until end of file is reached. I wanted to check how can I print no-match found only once after iterating through the entire file. Here is my sample code below

```
while IFS=, read -r path servicename app text1 text2 text3;
do
    text1="$key1"
    text2="$key2"
    text3="$key3"

    if [[ $servicename = $SERVICE_NAME ]];
    then
        if [[ $ENV = "sb" ]]; then
            ID="$key1"
        elif [[ $ENV = "lb" ]]; then
            ID="$key2"
        elif [[ $ENV = "dev" ]]; then
            ID="$key3"
        fi
    else
        echo "no match found"
    fi
done < $input_file
```

sample data that is used in the iteration

```
path,service,app,text1,text2,text3
path/of/service1,servicename1,appname,key1,key2,key3
path/of/service2,servicename2,appname,key1,key2,key3
path/of/service3,servicename3,appname,key1,key2,key3
path/of/service4,servicename4,appname,key1,key2,key3
path/of/service5,servicename5,appname,key1,key2,key3
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question. Thanks.

Comment: what you want to do is create a flag that holds "whether or not it found something" outside the loop, initialized to "false". Then, after you find something you actually want to print, switch it to "true". After you finish looping, check if the flag is "false", and if it is print "not found" at the end

Comment: Where do you assign content to variables `SERVICE_NAME` and `ENV`?

Comment: @JamesBrown I have added the sample data
@Esther something like this?
```
    match="false"
    if [[ $servicename = $SERVICE_NAME ]];
    then
        if [[ $ENV = "sb" ]]; then
            ID="$key1"
            match="true"
        fi
    elif [[ $match="true" ]];
    then
         echo "match found"
    else
        echo "no match found"
    fi
```
Tried that but does not seem to be working. I am not setting the flag correct maybe
@Cyrus it is outside the while loop. The issue is only with the if else loop so I have just that here.

Comment: I'd write the search of `$input_file`  in `awk` and simply have `awk` print the value of `$4`, `$5` or `$6` on match (or `"not found"` in the `END` rule) and assign the result to a `ID` variable via *Command Substitution* and then just check if  `$ID = "not found"` as a validation in your script. No loop required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable that keeps track if a match was found or not, and display the message at the end only.

Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICE_NAME="blablabla"
ENV="blablabla"
input_file="input.txt"

match_found="no"

while IFS=, read -r path servicename app text1 text2 text3
do
    text1="$key1"
    text2="$key2"
    text3="$key3"

    if [[ "$servicename" == "$SERVICE_NAME" ]]
    then
        match_found="yes"
        if [[ "$ENV" == "sb" ]]
        then
            ID="$key1"
        elif [[ "$ENV" == "lb" ]]
        then
            ID="$key2"
        elif [[ "$ENV" == "dev" ]]
        then
            ID="$key3"
        fi
    fi
done < "$input_file"

if [[ "$match_found" == "no" ]]
then
    printf "No match found\n"
fi
```

Another couple modifications:

- used `==` in the if conditions to check if text matches
- all variables use is double quoted
- I had to set a couple global variables to some bogus values to test my answer.  When you ask a question, you should provide a complete minimal sample.

Comment: You actually need to move `match_found="yes"` inside each of the `if` and `elif` blocks because you can have `"$servicename" == "$SERVICE_NAME"` and then no `$ENV` match. Setting on just  `"$servicename" == "$SERVICE_NAME"` will give a false positive in that case.

Comment: No, in the OP's code, the message is printed only if `servicename != SERVICE_NAME`.  I did not see the question mention that requirement, but that could be a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! `==` definitely